finding an event schedule given the duration and possible timeslots
I am trying to find or wondering if you know about an algorithm that could be used in a specific event scheduling task:

given a list of events e with length Ne where each event has:

a duration d (in minutes)
a list of possible timeslots t (in date/time) with length Nt (usually 1-3)

come up with a possible list of one timeslot each per event, so that the time in-between timeslots is maximised

just from trying to wrap my head around it for a bit I think that this might need a similar approach as creating a school timetable but having little experience with this I am not 100% sure if my specific restrictions change a lot

It seams the "time in-between timeslots is maximised" is the tricky part. How exactly is that meant? The smallest "time in-between" should be maximal? The sum of all "time in-between" should be maximal?

Genetic Algorithm might be a good approach here.  Seems like a dumb-down timetabling problem which can be solved using GAs.

@Jaco Van Niekerk: It's not only about finding a solution a good solution, it's about the best (maximize) solution which cannot be ensured using a genetic algorithm.
